# 3-dof Kinematics dh table

Tags: kinematics

[image]

Hello, I have some questions about kinematics. There are three of them:

1. When we align (z_o) with the z-axis, how should we define the x and y directions? It seems like pointing the right-hand thumb upwards and aligning with the rotation direction of (z_o), but I'm confused and not sure which is x and y.
2. I understand that the angle between (z_o) and (z_1) is 90 degrees, but I also considered that it could be -90 degrees. I think this confusion arises from not being able to solve the first question.
3. Could you please check the DH table for me? Thank you!"

Comment: You seem to be asking a number of different questions. Please [edit] your post and ask only one. Please see [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/280335)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can choose $x_0, y_0$ as you want as long as they with $z_0$ form a right hand coordinate system. That only applies with $x_0, y_0$ as for the other frames, DH rules apply